# Let $a$ be an odd positive integer, then $a^nx=\alpha_n+\beta_n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation

let $a$ be an odd positive integer and let $x$ be any real number. Why it's true that $$a^nx=\alpha_n+\beta_n,$$ where $\alpha_n$ is an integer and $-\frac{1}{2}\le \beta_n<\frac{1}{2}$.

I did some tests and it works, but I can't explain why. I hope someone can clarify my doubt. Thank you.

Comment: *Every* real number can be written as $\alpha_n+\beta_n$ with an integer $\alpha_n$ and $-\frac{1}{2}\le \beta_n<\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @MartinROk, but what is the motivation for this?

Answer (score 2):

The $a^n x$ is a red herring, so let's just replace it with an arbitrary real number $r$:
$$
r = \alpha(r) + \beta(r)
$$
where $\alpha(r)$ is an integer, and $\beta(r) \in [-\frac 1 2 , \frac 1 2]$.

All this is saying is that, for any real number $r$, there is an integer $\alpha(r)$ a distance $\beta(r)$ of at most $1/2$ away from it. (In fact, if $r$ is exactly halfway between two integers, then there are two plausible pairs of $\alpha,\beta$.)

To see this, just notice that the farthest you can get away from integer numbers is to be exactly halfway between a pair of consecutive integers. For instance, you cannot be further from integers than $1/2$ is from $0$ and $1$.